# How to assign attribut value of type Boolean in a class using Actions in Activity diagram?

Tags: uml, action

Problem description:

I have two attributes with Boolean type in class:Light

- on:Boolean
- off:Boolean

There are **four operations** implemented in behavior as an activity diagram using Actions from UML2:

- set_on()
- get_on(),
- set_off(),
- get_off()

in set_on the attribute "on" of type Boolean should have either 'True' or 'False' 
I think I should use"AddStructuralFeatureValueAction" but I am not completely sure

> 11.3.5: AddStructuralFeatureValueAction (from IntermediateActions) is a write structural feature action for adding values to a structural
>   feature.

but the problem is I don't know how it should be used(modeled)in Activity diagram

in get_on() it returns the current value of attribute but I don't what is the appropraite UML action for this case and how it should be used(modeled) in Activity diagram

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is not in your UML understanding, but in the structure you set. It doesn't fit the task. In life the light cannot be on and simultaneously off. And in your model it can. And you naturally got lost.

The class Light will have members:

fields: private boolean state,
possible set of public functions: void turnOn(), void turnOff(), boolean switchState(), boolean getState(), setState(boolean state).

I hope, the actions of THESE functions are obvious.

*(If you are modelling class functions, make class diagram before activity diagram, too.)*

Answer (score 2):

Extending the answer from Gangnus (which I find fully correct, with upvote), I would strongly recommend you to invest sime time in learning OO in general, class diagrams and class modelling. In practice the class diagam often sets the overall underlaying structure for your model, sets the logic, the rules... All other diagrams are kind of relyed on the acuretly modelled domain objects (or data objects if you wish).

In your example (again - as Gangus said), you modelled your class quite wrong. It is enough to have one boolean variable to determine if the light if on or off.

Regarding the AddStructuralFeatureValueAction, I would simply forget it for now. All these actions and their detailed understanding are much more needed for meta-modelling, than for modelling in a "real world" project.

Activity diagram is a great tool, but the abstraction that will be perfect for you is that it SOME tasks that eventually manipulate some data to achieve some goal. Concentrate to identify correctly those "tasks" instead of mapping them on formal UML metamodel (types of actions). Simply use general purpose action.

Turning on the light could be modelled like this (based on the class proposed by Gangnus):

[image]

If you want to show invokation of class's methods, consider **sequence diagrams**.